# Why is the subtraction result equal to NaN

Tags: javascript

In my code, I have a line of code that makes this mysterious result of NaN, always:

```
console.log("The dragon now has"+ (4-totalDamage) + "health left!")
```

Now `totalDamage` is equal to itself plus a variable called `damageThisRound`, which is a random integer from 1 to 5 (including 1 and 5 too). Now I would expect this line to log some like:

```
The dragon now has 1 health left!
```

but instead, I get:

```
The dragon now has NaNhealth left!
```

Why is the result equal to NaN instead of an integer like 1, 2, or 3 (which should be the only possible results of `(4-totalDamage)`)?

Full code:

```
var slaying = true
var youHit = Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
var damageThisRound = Math.floor(Math.random*5 + 1)
var totalDamage = 0

while (slaying) {
  if (youHit) {
      console.log("You hit the dragon!");
      totalDamage += damageThisRound;
      if (totalDamage >= 4) {
          console.log("You defeated the mighty dragon!");
          slaying = false;
      } else {
          console.log("The dragon now has"+ (4-totalDamage) + "health left!")
          youHit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
      }
  } else {
  console.log("You lose!");
  slaying = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show a complete code example so that we can reproduce the issue. Specifically showing how `totalDamage` is set.

Comment: totalDamage is probably in a string format. try : `4-parseInt(totalDamage)` (and be sure that totalDamage is not already NaN from a previous addition with the random number)

Comment: `totalDamage` is `NaN` or cannot be converted to a valid number. Provide a complete example.

Comment: @dievardump: It's fine for `totalDamage` to be a string, as long as it can be converted to a number.

Comment: Math.random() not Math.random at the 3rd line.

Comment: `Math.random` is a **function**, it has to be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `var damageThisRound = Math.floor(Math.random*5 + 1)` by `var damageThisRound = Math.floor(Math.random()*5 + 1)`

You forgot the `()` when calling `Math.random()`.

`Math.random*5` is`NaN`
Then `damageThisRound` is `NaN` and so is `totalDamage` because you try to add `NaN` to it.